# Delete every row that is not the first duplicate

Tags: postgresql, duplication

I want to enforce uniqueness on a column, but in order to do so, I need to manually clean up a lot of duplicates. I have found out that all the duplicates have no references to them, so a simple sorting by resh id and then manually deleting every duplicate resh id apart from the first one with works (a la `DELETE FROM org_units WHERE id in (3,4,5)`), but it is boring, so of course I would like to create some kind of query to clean up this mess.

The data looks like this:

```
org_units
ID  | RESH_ID
-------------
1   |  a
2   |  b
3   |  a
4   |  a
5   |  b
6   |  c
```

A first step would perhaps to do some kind of ordering:

```
select id, resh_id from org_unit order by resh_id, id;
```

I am not sure how to go from here to deleting everything apart from the first row in each "group" (group by might be handy?).

I would like to end up with a situation like

```
ID  | RESH_ID
-------------
1   |  a
2   |  b
6   |  c
```

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583916/delete-duplicate-rows-from-small-table

Answer (score 1):

This removes all rows apart from the first in each group ordered by resh id:

```
DELETE FROM org_unit o 
WHERE o.id NOT IN 
  (SELECT MIN(ID) AS id 
   FROM  org_unit 
   GROUP BY resh_id  
   ORDER BY resh_id);
```

If you wanted the last two or three, you would use the window function `ROW_NUMBER` and select the wanted number

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "org_units" (
>   "ID" INTEGER,
>   "RESH_ID" VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO "org_units"
>   ("ID", "RESH_ID")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'a'),
>   ('2', 'b'),
>   ('3', 'a'),
>   ('4', 'a'),
>   ('5', 'b'),
>   ('6', 'c');
> ```

> ```
>   DELETE FROM "org_units" o 
> where o."ID" in (SELECT MIN("ID")    FROM  "org_units" GROUP BY "RESH_ID" )
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM org_units
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | RESH_ID
> -: | :------
>  3 | a      
>  4 | a      
>  5 | b
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE org_units2 (
>   "ID" INTEGER,
>   "RESH_ID" VARCHAR(1)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO org_units2
>   ("ID", "RESH_ID")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'a'),
>   ('2', 'b'),
>   ('3', 'a'),
>   ('4', 'a'),
>   ('5', 'b'),
>   ('6', 'c');
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM "org_units2" o 
> where o."ID" NOT in (SELECT MIN("ID")    FROM  "org_units2" GROUP BY "RESH_ID" )
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM org_units2
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | RESH_ID
> -: | :------
>  1 | a      
>  2 | b      
>  6 | c
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e090da928bcd492a55ce14a5f5d19ba8)*